# Why does this logo stick to the top on mobile devices?

Tags: css, mobile

http://mobiletest.me/nokia_lumia_920_emulator/#u=http://syntheticturfdrs.com

I can't seem to figure out how to remove my logo from the side when panning down. I've narrowed it down to the  , but I have to keep that in there to keep it properly aligned. It only happens when i'm on a mobile advice.

Comment: Perhaps that logo has `position: fixed;` in `CSS`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a div in your code which has a class of `skel-panels-overlay`, this div has an inline style with `position:fixed` which is what is fixing the logo in the same place.
If its only on a mobile, chances are that this is being set by a script which is adding the inline css.

the "," has nothing to do with the problem here. You have a css rule which is `*, *::before, *::after` that is just applying a `box-sizing` rule to every element on the site.

Comment: You were spot on! Also, I was referring to `<div class='skel-panels-overlay` in my earlier post, but it was commented out. Thank you for the help!